# CSS Gallery with responsive margin

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a a gallery of sorts that have equal amount of spacing between each items, fills out the entire width of the container div and adds items to a new row after that. So far I got this, which works fine in every regard except for that the margin is not responsive (and by that does not fill out the window). Tried different solutions such as: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/3/ which did not work properly.

```
<html>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.movie-container {
    width: 11em;
    height: 16.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}

.movie {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

.poster {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

</style>
<div id="main-container">
<div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="21374218" class="movie-container">
    <div class="movie"><img class="poster" src="/1.jpg"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's about using [display: flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Designating_a_Flexible_Box) and [justify-content: space-between](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)? Also, you don't need to use different classes for each box, you could use [:nth-child(even)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector. Check this out:

```css
.container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: 125px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* just for demo */
    min-width: 612px;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    background: #ccc
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
    background: #0ff
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/z14eh81m/2/)